# Pascal. Unidirectional list. Loop

Tags: pascal

Here is an example program from a book. I can't stop the "while not eof" loop. I tried to insert in program "Uses crt;", "const CheckEof: boolean=true" and to press "ctrl+Z" while running, it doesn't work.

```
Program P123;
uses 
  crt; {My insertion}

type 
   Adresacelula = ^Celula;

   Celula = record
     Info: string;
     Urm: AdresaCelula;
   end;

var 
  P, Q, R: AdresaCelula;
  s: string;
  i: integer;

const 
  CheckEOF: boolean = true; {My insertion}

  Procedure Create;
  begin
    p := nil;
    write ('s='); readln (s);
    new (r); r^.Info := s; r^.Urm := nil;
    p := r; q := r;
    write ('s=');
       
    while not eof do {Here is the loop i need to stop}
    begin
      readln (s); write ('s=');
      new (r); r^.Info := s; r^.Urm := nil;
      q^.Urm := r; q := r;
    end;
  end;

  Procedure Display;
  begin
    r := p;

     while r<>nil do
     begin
       writeln (r^.Info);
       r := r^.Urm;
     end;

     readln;
   end;

 begin
   Create;
   Display;

 end.
```

Comment: EOF will become true only when the pipe connected to stdin is terminated. You'll need another way to do this except for stdin unless you are only using it for piping.   Crt overrides stdin/out and shouldn't be used in such case at all.

Comment: f:=true;
  while f do
  begin
   write ('s='); readln (s);
   if s='ENDENDEND123123^^^' then f:=false
   else
     begin
  new (r); r^.Info:=s; r^.Urm:=nil;
  q^.Urm:=r; q:=r;
     end;
  end;

Comment: but i think isnt the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the example work, remove the line

`const CheckEOF: boolean=true; {My insertion}`

and insert `CheckEOF:=true;` before the `Create;` call in the main program. Then the program terminates when you press Ctrl-Z.

Your code declares a new variable `CheckEOF` while you probably want to change `CheckEOF` of the `crt` unit.